# jQuery - Clone div only when dropped

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-droppable

how can I create a "clone" of a certain div only when dropped? this clone should be in the same point when you start to drag and ready to be dragged again.

For example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0ozboau/1/)  is possible to clone the green elements, in the initial position, only when they are dropped?

this is my JS:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dragrabble-one").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-two").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-three").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-four").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-five").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-six").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-seven").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-eight").draggable({
    helper: 'clone'
  });
  $("#dragrabble-one").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-two").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-three").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-four").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-five").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-six").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-seven").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#dragrabble-eight").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
  $("#droppable-box").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var clone = ui.helper.clone();
      clone.draggable();
      clone.appendTo('#droppable-box');
    }
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A,
A solution could be, to hide the cloned element with opacity equals 0 when the user starts dragging the element and setting the opacity back to 1 when dragging has stopped.

```
$("#dragrabble-one").draggable({

    helper: 'clone',
    start: function (event, ui){
        $(this).css('opacity','0');
    },
    stop: function (event, ui){
        $(this).css('opacity','1');
    }

});
```

I hope this helps you! :)